# Debugging Validation Errors In Craft

Tags: plugin-development, tasks, debugging

Is it obvious why the task validation errors are not getting output in my log:

```
public function runStep($step)
{
    try
    {
        $entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($this->_entryIds[$step], $this->_localeId);

        if (!$entry)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $newExpiryDate = new DateTime($entry->date);
        $newExpiryDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));


        // Update Expiry Date
        if($entry->expiryDate != $newExpiryDate)
        {
            $entry->expiryDate = $newExpiryDate->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        // Update Status
        $entry->enabled = true;

        // Save Entry
        if(craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry))
        {
            return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Encountered the following validation errors when trying to save entry with the ID "'.$entry->id.'":';

            foreach ($entry->getAllErrors() as $attributeError)
            {
                $error .= "\n - {$attributeError}";
            }

            return $error;              
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return 'An exception was thrown while trying to save the entry with the ID “'.$this->_entryIds[$step].'”: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This task step is based on one of the Craft default steps but the error gets output without the specific validation issues:

> Encountered an error running task 1191 (Logic_UpdateEvents), step 1 of 1440: Encountered the following validation errors when trying to save entry with the ID "10295":

Comment: What happens if you `Craft::log('error count = '.count($entry->getAllErrors()));`

Comment: `error count = 1`

Comment: Looks O.K. to me.  What if you do: `Craft::log('error = '.$entry->getAllErrors[0]);`?

Comment: `Encountered an error running task 1193 (Logic_UpdateEvents), step 1 of 1440: An exception was thrown while trying to save the entry with the ID “10295”: Property "Craft\EntryModel.getAllErrors" is not defined.`

Comment: Wait a second surely that needs to be `Craft::log('error = '.$entry->getAllErrors()[0])` ?

Comment: That returns the error correctly!

Comment: Any idea what caused the issue with the existing code?

Comment: I've tested a few variations but the line which is pumping out the errors `$error .= "\n - {$attributeError}";` is not happy with \n PHP_EOL, it would be great to know how to get line breaks output into the logs and awesome to get this fixed in the craft core versions.

Comment: Try using `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Already tried. No go. :(

Comment: @BradBell Ive discovered that this exact task works as expected when Dev Mode is off! not sure if that helps explain anything??

Comment: That's really weird!